# Achieve parallelogram images with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i need to achieve this for a web site but I'm having trouble giving the images the right shape, and the pink and blue background.
I need it to be responsive, but right now al the css form lost its form when I try it in smaller screens.

[image]

Currently my code is this, any help would be very appreciated, thank you in advance.

```css
   

who { 
    font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    margin-top: -9.5%;
    margin-right: 12px;
}




.skewed {
  background: white;
  width: 25%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(30deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(30deg);
  transform: skewX(-40deg);
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.skewed img {
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:-20px;
    overflow: hidden;
   transform: skewX(40deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
</head>

<body>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="skewed">
            <img class="img-responsive dist" src="http://imagenpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/wallpaper3-1024x639.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="skewed">
            <img class="img-responsive dist" src="http://imagenpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/wallpaper3-1024x639.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="skewed">
            <img class="img-responsive dist" src="http://imagenpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/wallpaper3-1024x639.jpg">
          </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
   

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a white background like in the example you could rotate some objects with `:before` and `:after` on the element with the class "skewed". You might need to adjust the top and left positioning of my example to fit your images.

**CSS**

```
.skewed {
  position: relative;
}
.skewed:before,
.skewed:after {
  content: "";
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
}
.skewed:before {
  top: -100px;
  left: -350px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.skewed:after {
  top: -100px;
  left: 350px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/dez8ayu1/)